# page-node-nid.tpl.php is not used as template file

Tags: theming, 6

I am using the following code.

```
function chgakitheme_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {
  if ($vars['user']->uid == 0 && arg(0) == 'user' && (arg(1) == '' || arg(1) == 'login')) {
    array_unshift($vars['template_files'], 'page-login');
    $vars['body_classes'] .= ' userlogin';
  }

  if (isset($vars['node'])) {
   $vars['template_files'][] = 'page-'. str_replace('_', '-', $vars['node']->type);
  }
}
```

Now I can use page-nodetype.tpl.php, but I can't use page-node-nid.tpl.php because Drupal doesn't see it.

I need all types of template files. I want a template specific for a content type.

What can I do? Can I do this in Drupal 6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [Drupal 6 Template suggestions](https://drupal.org/node/1089642), The list of suggested template files is in order of specificity based on internal paths. One suggestion is made for every element of the current path, though numeric elements are not carried to subsequent suggestion, order of execution is as below:

- page-node-edit.tpl.php
- page-node-**[node_id]**.tpl.php
- page-node.tpl.php
- page.tpl.php

> So basically you don't need to use the "TEMPLATE_preprocess_page" for using "page-node-[node_id].tpl.php" for template suggestion as it is provided by default. May be the problem is of "clearing the cache", try once after **clearing the cache**.

In Drupal6,  `page-node-[node_type].tpl.php` is not available by default, to make it work we customize the suggestions in the `TEMPLATE_preprocess_page` as done by you.

If you want more specific templates than you can customize the template suggestions as your requirement in `TEMPLATE_preprocess_page`. Example as below:

```
// Implement TEMPLATE_preprocess_page.
function TEMPLATE_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['node']->type !== '') {
    // For using "page-node-[node_type].tpl.php" for template suggestion.
    $variables['template_files'][] = "page-node-" . $variables['node']->type;

    // For using "page-node-[node_type]-[node_id].tpl.php" for template suggestion.
    $variables['template_files'][] = "page-node-" . $variables['node']->type . "-" . $variables['node']->nid;
  }
}
```

After using the above code you can use the additional template suggestion as below:

- page-node-[node_type]-[node_id].tpl.php
- page-node-[node_type].tpl.php

**NOTE:** Don't forget to **clear the cache** after making changes to template files otherwise the changes won't reflect back.

Comment: page-node-[node_type]-[node_id].tpl.php is work, but page-node-[node_type].tpl.php in not work

Comment: Important: if i use MYTHEMENAME_preprocess_page - work page-node-[node_type]-[node_id].tpl.php, in i use PHPTHEMPLATE_preprocess_page - work page-node-[node_type].tpl.php. If i use first and second - don't work page-node-[node_type]-[node_id].tpl.php

Comment: Sorry - this is work! But need: PHPTEMPLATE_preprocess_page